# Is this function periodic? What's its period? $f(x)=\frac{a+b\cos(x_1-x)}{(c+d\cos(x_1-x))^{3/2}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is the following function periodic? How do I find its period (if it is periodic)?

$$f(x) = \frac{a+b\cos(x_1-x)}{(c+d\cos(x_1-x))^{3/2}} $$

Here $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are constants (positive or negative, non-zero) and $0\leq x_1 \leq 2\pi$. Based on the period of $cos(x_1-x)$, I think that the period of the function is $2\pi$ and it's easy to verify that:

$$ f(x+2\pi) = f(x) $$

I made a graph of the function and it displays a periodic behaviour with a period of $2\pi$.

What's the best way to determine the period of this function without guessing or looking at the graph of the function?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Hi! It's easy to demonstrate that $f(x+2\pi) = f(x)$ so I assume that the period is $2\pi$. I made this attempt based on the period of $cos(x_1-x)$ but given that this is a rational function, I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it. The graph of the function displays a periodic behaviour with a period of $2\pi$ as well.

Comment: @Desty: Welcome to Math.SE! (Also, thanks! :)  ... Comments are easily overlooked, so you should include what you've tried in the body of the question itself. That way, everyone can see right away that you already know that the function *is* periodic, and that you've verified graphically that the period is $2\pi$, but that you want to know the best way to handle this. In general, telling how much you know and/or exactly where you got stuck helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without telling you things you already know or using techniques with which you are unfamiliar.

Comment: Might be useful that $f(x_1-\pi/2)=f(x_1-\pi/2-T)$ where $T$ is the period so $\frac{a}{c^{3/2}}=\frac{a+b\cos(\pi/2+T)}{(c+d\cos(\pi/2+T))^{3/2}}$ you could try with other known values like $f(x_1)=f(x_1-T)$ or $f(x_1-\pi/4)=f(x_1-\pi/4-T)$ etc.